# Steps: point application to Web (instead of 'localhost')

Tags: linux, spring, tomcat, web

I have a question on how to go about posting a page to the Internet using Spring STS Framework with Tomcat container (I am using Linux). I have a basic Hello World program created and able to bring it up within `http://localhost:8080/mypage`.

I have checked the following sites so far, but have not found a definitive process: `SpringSource.org`, `Apache.org`, and `StackOverflow.com`, and `AskUbuntu.com`

I noticed one possible way is to add IP address and Domain name to the /etc/hosts file. If it is as simple as that, I will go ahead and purchase a domain name/address.

**If it is not as simple as that, what are the steps to be able to have this page display onto the Internet?**

Comment: Something like `http://davidsapp.com/hello`? Yes, you'll have to purchase a domain name for that.

Comment: So, it is as simple as purchasing a domain name, and then adding that identifying information to the hosts file? If so, that is excellent!!

Comment: Thought to add an example of what it might look like if I then alter the hosts file: http://pastebin.com/m0RTFacH

Comment: NO, no that's just the beginning. You'll have to buy the domain, then pay for hosting your site as well. Your domain name's dns will point to your hosting server. (You don't need to change your HOSTS file.) Basic linux hosting comes with PHP and MySQL. For Spring STS I think you'll have to ask your hosting service if they can provide that.

Comment: By 'hosting service' do you mean something like go daddy? Or, is it possible to just purchase a domain name and host it myself?

Comment: Do you want your application to be accessible online (other people should be able to use it from their Internet connection) or you just want to run it locally but display a domain name in your browser? (So that it looks cool :)

Comment: It needs to be accessible online. So, I know I will need to either use a service that provides a URL or purchase a domain name and then either still employ some type of service like go daddy or purchase a domain name and host it with a dedicated box from home. This is just a home lab situation (at least at this point).

Comment: Yes, your understanding of things is correct. If you're just testing the waters better go for a free domain service and point your domain to your machine. For this to work you'll need a static IP. If you have a dynamic IP use a service like `noip.com`.

Comment: I will have to investigate that. I have both a cable modem and a router. So, while I believe I have a dynamic IP, the fact that I have a router leads me to think I should verify this somehow - just to make sure. I appreciate your comments. It helps, for sure.

Comment: Dynamic connections use a cable modem mostly. Since, you have a router in between better read up on port forwarding as well. In short, your machine and router would be on a local LAN with static or dynamic (internal) IPs (192.168.* or 10.1.* etc.) based on how you've configured DHCP. The other end of your router connected with the modem would have the external IP (assigned by the ISP).

Comment: By the way, StackOverflow doesn't suit the type of your question. You won't find much help here. Better post at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Makes sense. That site (serverfault) is where I have somewhat related bookmark saved, actually. Thank you Ravi, I appreciate all this and the fact that you mentioned that site as well.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Good luck with your home lab. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question will occur in the process of taking further steps.

**Assumption:** this question may not have been posted on the correct forum within StackExchange. Upon Ravi's suggestion, it may be better suited for the serverfault forum.

The intent in asking this question was to get a few general ideas on direction, however the question was specific steps. Since there may be several variables to answer this question accurately involving cable modem, router, 'server' settings, and IDE settings for example, this is going to involve smaller more segmented questions that are specific in nature.

**Steps to be taken:**

1. Re-phrase question to smaller segment or ask for more general
       response.
2. Post to serverfault forum.
3. If I have further questions, break them down in small segments,
   investigate.